# Video plays for a few and doesnt for others

Tags: video, youtube

http://youtu.be/x4_DjOHUFhc
I had uploaded this video. Sadly only a few can view it and few cant.
Its set as Public
It says video not available. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is either a temporary problem for the video, or it's a problem on their computers. It plays fine on mine and it seems to be public.

Comment: I tried on my phone too.. Some way, few of my friends are able to view it, and few others are arent.
Coz of the background music I know it doesnt play in Germany, but the rest of the world all should be able to view it, but it doesnt happen so.